# Domain Specific Language Bloggers

Tags: blogs, dsl

I have a current need to greatly increase my knowledge around DSLs. Who are the big names in DSLs? What blogs should I be reading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Martin Fowler has written a [book on DSLs](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#dsl) ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321712943)).  Ayende Rahien has completed a [book](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/03/02/building-domain-specific-languages-with-boo-ndash-full-book-now.aspx) on writing DSLs in Boo, which also is [available online](http://www.manning.com/rahien/) via Manning's early access program.  The former is conceptual while the latter is a practical guide.

Comment: +1 Do you know what Ayende uses as a domain for his DSL in the book? I have read the first chapter it seems really good. But still rough around the edges.

Answer (score 5):

You can read a lot of interesting stuff about language design on the [Lambda the Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/) blog.

Answer (score 2):

[Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/) is the first one that jumps to mind. He has links to other resources on his page, too.

Answer (score 2):

I know that's an old question, but I enjoy reading eelco visser's [blog](http://blog.eelcovisser.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Martin Fowler and Eric Evans for a start.

Jimmy Nilsson perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

[Paul Hudak](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/hudak-paul/) is one of the people who worked on Haskell, and has written [this paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=242477) about implementing embedded DSLs in Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

[Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com/Blog/category/547.aspx) blogs about various things, including DSLs via Boo